# C++ macro causing null pointer

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor, access-violation

I was wondering if someone can explain this macro to me.

```
#define Q_DECLARE_PRIVATE(Class) \

inline Class##Private* d_func() { return reinterpret_cast<Class##Private
*>(d_ptr); } \

inline const Class##Private* d_func() const { return reinterpret_cast<const
Class##Private *>(d_ptr); } \

friend class Class##Private;
```

I have an application that uses QT and it crashes with an access violation exception on the last line from the following snippet.

```
class Q_GUI_EXPORT QWidget : public QObject, public QPaintDevice
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_DECLARE_PRIVATE(QWidget)
```

([full source here](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/blobs/master/src/gui/kernel/qwidget.h))

and what can cause a null pointer operation in on the last line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler can explain it best of all:

```
g++ -E foo.cc
```

will put foo.cc to stdout after passing through the pre-processor. It lets you see what the compiler sees which (especially with token pasting) is usually less than obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Is your `this` pointer `NULL`? All that code does is generate access functions for the `d_ptr` class member.

Comment: This line is hit when I'm instantiating a class that inherits from  `QListView` which, way down the chain, indirectly inherits from `QWidget` that is shown in the question.

Comment: Can you confirm whether the `this` pointer is NULL when the exception occurs?

Answer (score 1):

The macros implement a Pimpl idiom by declaring a pointer to a private implementation class. The `##` garbage is creating a name for the private class using the preprocessor catenation operator.

If retrieving the `d_ptr` member causes a NULL access, then the caller must be doing `NULL->d_func()`. Look for that and debug the caller.

Answer (score 1):

From Windows header:

```
#define DECLARE_HANDLE(name) struct name##__ {int unused;} typedef name##__* name;
```

And usage:

```
DECLARE_HANDLE(YourHandeType); // Just any name, this isn't any type
```

Would create new struct as:

```
struct YourHandleType__
{ 
   int unused;
};
typedef YourHandleType__ * YourHandleType;
```

Where `YourHandleType` would be pointer of type `YourHandleType__`

The tokenizer operator `##` would be used by preprocessor to make full name, which will be utilized by C/C++ compiler. In this case `DECLARE_HANDLE` can create different types that would be opaque to caller, and still providing "no conversion" between different handles.